# Optimizing a function under strictly positive constraint

Tags: optimization, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

Find x and y that optimise

\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= (-a-y)(\Psi(y)-\Psi(x+y)) + (b-x)(\Psi(x)-\Psi(x+y)) \\
&-\log \Gamma(x+y) + \log\Gamma(x) + \log\Gamma(y)
\end{align}

where a, b are strictly positive constant.

Taking the derivative of $f(x,y)$ w.r.t. $x$, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = (b-x)\Psi'(x) - (b-x-a-y)\Psi'(x+y)
\end{align*}

Taking the derivative of $f(x,y)$ w.r.t. $y$, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = (-a-y)\Psi'(y)-(b-x-a-y)\Psi'(x+y)
\end{align*}

It gives $x = b$ and $y = -a$ which means $y<0$ since $a>0$. Here $\Psi$ is digamma and $\Psi'$ is trigamma.

How can I proceed from here to optimise $f(x,y)$ such that $x > 0$ and $y > 0$.?

Comment: What are the functions $\Psi$ and $\Gamma$?

Comment: $\Psi$ is digamma function and $\Gamma$ is gamma function.

Comment: In general, nonlinear optimization models and algorithms are not capable of handling strict inequality constraints. The typical way to handle this is to instead require $x \ge \epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 If we introduce $x \ge \epsilon$ then is $y = \epsilon$ the solution?

Comment: This kind of problem arises in maximum likelihood estimation (MLE). In that setting, a function is maximized over the strictly positive orthant, but we don’t have to worry about the boundary because the function blows up there.

Comment: @DavidM. In MLE situation, if the parameter is supposed to be +ve, but it is estimated as -ve, what can we do?

Comment: I spoke too soon--this problem is not well-posed. If you fix $y\neq0$, then $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x,y)=-\infty$. But if you fix $x\neq0$, then $\lim_{y\to0^+}f(x,y)=+\infty$. So this function is unbounded in both directions over the positive quadrant.

Comment: @DavidM. Thus this means there is no solution for $x$ and $y$. I was running MLE, and $a$ is some value of function of other parameters. To update $x$ and $y$, fixing other parameters and thus having a fixed $a$. It leads me to this condition that $a >0$.  Can I not proceed MLE from here.

Comment: I would post a new question containing more details about the MLE you’re carrying out.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimizing a function"?  Do you want to find a minimum?

Comment: @ThePheromoneKid I want to maximise the function.